# Parent-child fragment communication Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), fragments should always communicate through associated activity, they should never communicate direct.
Why is that so ?
Let's say I have `fragment_A` containing a listview filled with some books titles, these books are sorted by the user's rating. Whenever a user click at some book title in listview, another `fragment_B` will be opened (A is parent of B), B contains some details about this book, user can also rate the book in this fragment. I want this rating to be reflected in the parent `fragment_A`.

I would get a reference from B to his parent by `getParentFragment()` to do some changes in A, but according to google, I should call the associated activity to obtain a interface's reference, this interface gives me the ability to communicate with the parent fragment in my case, why is that so ? why shouldn't I simply use the `getParentFragment()` method ? Is it possible that parent fragment is destroyed (or somehow not accessible from child fragment), while the child fragment is still alive ?

Thank you!

Comment: In general, the documentation refers to top-level fragments, not nested fragments. In particular, nothing in that tutorial page has anything to do with nested fragments.

Comment: So is it OK to communicate between child-parent fragment using the getParentFragment() method, or is it possible that, that parent fragment is not accessible from child fragment ?

Comment: I'd say that holding reference from one fragment to another is just a bad practice. When designing your components, try to minimise coupling between your classes.

Comment: "So is it OK to communicate between child-parent fragment using the getParentFragment() method" -- I avoid nested fragments outright and do not use them. I cannot advise you on patterns there. All I am pointing out is that the documentation, unless it is *specifically* discussing nested fragments, usually is referring to top-level fragments.